# Setting locale in Travis-CI (when sudo is not allowed)

Tags: ubuntu, travis-ci, gettext

I've a multilanguage (English and Italian) application written in R building/deploying on Travis-CI under Ubuntu Trusty environment and I would like to test all the localized messages. The application is using the gettext model.

The localized versions are under the `LC_MESSAGES` subfolders, where they are supposed to be.

I've installed the Italian apt `language-pack-it`, but Ubuntu won't seem to switch to Italian as all.

This is my locale set when I switch to Italian:

```
LC_CTYPE=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=C
LC_ADDRESS=C
LC_TELEPHONE=C
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

It looks like the switch is not "complete" (look for ex. the `LC_MESSAGES` value)

I cannot use the `sudo locale-gen "it_IT.UTF-8"` (not sure it would solve anyway) as Travis won't allow `sudo` on containers.

Is there another way to address the issue?

Here is the [app](https://github.com/9thcirclegames/wisdom-of-cthulhu/) I'm trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was more trivial as expected: `LC_ALL` doesn't set `LC_MESSAGES` by default, so I just had to set it in a set env command to solve the issue.